# Same urllib2-beautifulsoup4 code works on home computer but not on aws ec2 server

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2

So, I have this very simple python beautiful soup program that prints the 1st 1000 characters of a web page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

def soup_maker(url):
    class RedirectHandler(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler):
        def http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers):
            result = urllib2.HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, headers, fp)
            result.status = code
            return result



    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11',
                                'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                                'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
                                'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
                                'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
                                'Connection': 'keep-alive'}

    req = urllib2.Request(url,headers=hdr)
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(RedirectHandler())
    webpage = opener.open(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, "html5lib")
    return soup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'https://offerupnow.com/'
    print str(soup_maker(url))[0:1000]
```

On my home computer it outputs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US"><head>
    <title>OfferUp - Buy. Sell. Simple.</title>


    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta content="OfferUp, Offer Up, social shopping, online deals, classifieds, Buy local stuff, Local stuff for sale, Shop local, Local shopping, Local marketplace, Local yard sales, Local garage sales, Gently used baby stuff, Sell locally, Buy locally, Sell stuff online" name="keywords"/>
    <meta content="OfferUp is revolutionizing how we sell by making it a snap! Instantly connect with buyers and sellers near you." name="description"/>
    <meta content="hVckgnfxPSIIYHASW6k-BapqZdaFc19eRe0nI8CneNM" name="google-site-verification"/>
    <meta content="1d7e114ee3af2b13ced8508628f804b9" name="p:domain_verify"/>

    <meta content="NOODP" name="robots"/>
    <meta content="index,follow" name="robots"/>




    <meta content="summary" name="twitter:card"/>
    <meta content="@offerup" name="twitter:site"/>
    <meta content="OfferUp" name="twi
```

On my server it outputs:

```
<html><head>
<meta content="noindex,nofollow" name="robots"/>
<script>
(function() {  function getSessionCookies() {   cookieArray = new Array();   var cName = /^\s?incap_ses_/;   var c = document.cookie.split(";");   for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {    key = c[i].substr(0, c[i].indexOf("="));    value = c[i].substr(c[i].indexOf("=") + 1, c[i].length);    if (cName.test(key)) {     cookieArray[cookieArray.length] = value    }   }   return cookieArray  }  function setIncapCookie(vArray) {   try {    cookies = getSessionCookies();    digests = new Array(cookies.length);    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {     digests[i] = simpleDigest((vArray) + cookies[i])    }    res = vArray + ",digest=" + (digests.join())   } catch (e) {    res = vArray + ",digest=" + (encodeURIComponent(e.toString()))   }   createCookie("___utmvc", res, 20)  }  function simpleDigest(mystr) {   var res = 0;   for (var i = 0; i < mystr.length; i++) {    res += mystr.charCodeAt(i)   }   return res  }  fun
```

I would like my server to output the same thing as my home computer. I will accept any answer that allows my server to output the same stuff as my home computer.

Comment: It's possible that the site that you are scraping blocks requests from AWS IP addresses on the grounds that they are very likely to be scraping bots.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I think you may be correct, Is there a way to get around this?